# Какие инструменты лучше всего использовать для создания 2д графики и анимации под юнити?

Tags: unity3d, анимация, разработка-игр, flash

Нужно сделать **2D** графику для игры под юнити.

Встал вопрос, какой инструмент лучше для этого подходит. 
Само собой для рисования самих спрайтов использовать фотошоп (наверно).
А вот для анимации голову ломаю, не улавливаю сути.

Как я понял, для **2D** игр используют в основном покадровую анимацию, которую, в свою очередь, делают тремя способами: либо все спрайты рисуют в ручную (как я понял популярно в пиксель арте), либо с помощью инструментов перетаскивания слоев отдельных частей персонажа (там ножку подкрутят, там руку занесут, и типа походка получилась), либо полноценно с помощью скелетной анимации, которая идеально функционирует, но офк как бы сложнее, ибо настроить еще все ключи нужно, но на выходе можно анимации сделать очень много и быстро.

Вот тут не могу понять:

1. Что, собственно, выбрать? По идее, все зависит от того, сколько я хочу использовать графики в игре. Если анимации будет немного, то достаточно  спрайты сделать покадрово вручную.
   А если хочу делать много анимации, и качественной, то лучше использовать метод скелетной анимации, так?
2. Почему нельзя скелетную анимацию полностью использовать в игре? Почему  делают только покадровую нарезку, ведь анимация получается не такая идеальная? Вопрос в ресурсозадратах? Насколько большое различие? Или скелетная анимация в **3D** играх тоже как бы покадровая? С пониманием этим вопросом у меня проблема(((
3. Допустим, я хочу проработать своего персонажа с большим количеством анимации, поэтому выбираю скелетную, дабы добротно получилось. Какой инструмент лучше всего для этого подойдет?

Я так понимаю, программы для **3D** моделирования также отлично подходят и для **2D**. Тот же *Blender*, *3DMax*, *cinema 4D*, *maya* или крутые и дорогие программы именно для **2D** анимации - *spine* и *anime studio*/
 Какие основные критерии используют для выбора инструмента создании **2D** анимации?

И опять же, вроде как в самой *Unity* тоже можно делать ту самую покадровую скелетную анимацию с помощью `mecanim` (только еще не понял, кости можно прям в ней делать, или обязательно портировать модельку из **3D** редакторов). Так зачем использовать другие программы, если можно обойтись средствами в *Unity*?

Плюс есть платные ассеты на ту же *Unity* для скелетной анимации.

Что выбрать? 2 день гугл рою и в ру сегменте инфы про этом совсем прям чет мало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответом на Ваш вопрос является использование спрайтовой анимации. Она более гибкая для таких целей и допускает привязку скелетной реализации. Анимацию лучше всего задавать в самом Unity и удобно в ней то, что каждая анимация сохраняется отдельным действием. Т.е. в последующем её можно использовать в различных ситуациях. Не советую использовать сторонние инструменты при создании анимированных 2D элементов, так как если что-то пойдёт не так - концов вы не найдёте и всё равно придёте к варианту спрайтовой анимации.
**UPD:** Я переносил анимированный элемент из Blender, 3Ds Max, Cinema 4D и во всех случаях элемент не переносился качественно, либо не работали анимации, либо текстуры, либо что-то ещё, поэтому советую просто переносить модели и спрайты по частям, без анимации, чтобы в дальнейшем средствами Unity придать нужный эффект.

Comment: А под созданием анимации в самой юнити, вы имеете в виду использование расширений типа anime2d, Puppet2D ? Или есть стандартные инструменты для создания костной анимации в юньке, а расширения нужны только для удобства и большего функционала?

Comment: Я разобрался
anime2d от официальных разрабов, бесплатна, короче мастхев в моем случае

Comment: Да, в любом случае есть инструменты "из коробки" для таких вещей.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте прекрасный инструмент Anima2D, который продвигается самим Unity. по сути тот же самый Spine и DragonBones(китайский аналог Spine), только внутри среды Unity, т.е. ничего никуда не надо импортировать, тем самым все сохранится в первозданном виде.

уроки:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwx1hYGfxqUxe8--NbboYmqA6OFhOE34R

ассет:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/79840

Comment: Спасибо дружище)) на нём как раз и остановился, думаю если все получится, освою его, то уже потом можно и другие попробывать и потом сравнить что удобней=))